# instead of pswd for access to private file, how use series of inputs that must match saved strings"

Tags: file, passwords, store, private

I have a file in which there is sensitive data. I want only people who can answer 3 questions correctly to have access.  I do not want to have prior contact with these people to give them passwords.

I have found basic coding, but the 'correct' answers to the questions is sitting there in the html for all to see.  Does javascript have a way to store the 'correct' answers in another file, and check that the input answers equal the 'correct' answers?

I would think my problem is common, so can anyone give me links or search terms to find it elsewhere?

Comment: Is everything (sensitive data + challenge questions) in a single self-contained HTML file?

Comment: You'll need a server-side authorization method - client-side will always expose your sensitive data.

Comment: @Michael - I had not considered putting the private info I want protected in the same file as the answers to the questions, but I suppose they are equally private.  Is there are benefit from doing so?

Comment: @ Filbut - this file will be posted to those quasi-websites that my internet provider (shaw) provides for free with every email address.  Eg. http://members.shaw.ca/MYSITE , so I don't have access to their server.  Does your comment mean I am out of luck?

Comment: One way to do this in a single HTML file with JavaScript is to encrypt your data using the answers to your questions as the encryption key.

Comment: @Michael - That idea sounds possible.  Would it be something like.....  There is some way to encrypt the webpage so its HTML coding is gibberish.  The answer to each question "string" get added together to form another "3inputString".  That string would be the key to un-encrypt the webpage.  And javascript will do both ???   Can you give me some search terms to use to find the info I need to learn?   Thank you very much.

Comment: @to all .... **LATER**  I just thought of a way.  On a normal webpage ask people to answer three questions.  Then simply tell them to input a URL that is made up as eg http://www.mySite/string1string2string3.html .  I will put the sensitive data on that html page.

That just leaves me with the problem of preventing other people knowing that file exists   ??????? I know that browsers give you lists of files in sub-directories when you include the trailing / in a URL.  But I have never found a way to find a list of files in the same root folder as the .index.html.  *Can it be done????*